# get information from device path

Tags: performance, winapi, vb6, device

One of our legacy applications is producing resource leaks on 1 specific machine. Over time the overall processor usage increases until the application is closed and restarted.

Using `perfmon` I found a direct correlation between the process's handle count and the processor usage. This count went up into the thousands and I used SysInternal's `handle` to expose that all the extra handles (at least during the process running this afternoon when I ran `handle`) had a path of `\Device\00000066`.

I want to learn how to discover more information about exactly what device the device path is referring to so we know where to go from here. I have strong suspicions that the device is a PIN pad (used during debit transactions), but need proof.

Windows XP sp3.

**Resolution**
After Seva Titov's advice helped me identify it was a USB device, I had one main suspect: a cash drawer. We had the client unplug it and use it manually for a few hours: no constant increase in handles. I looked through that project's code and the developer neglected to close handles to the device after obtaining them. The rapid increase in handles was due to a timer that checked the drawer's status after it was opened to determine when the user had closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get more information on the kernel directory object:

1. Install [LiveKd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415), install [Windows Debugging Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)
2. Launch LiveKd in the directory that contains kd.exe
3. Inside LiveKd prompt type this:

```
    !object \device\00000066
```

Then use the value that it shows for the object (the first it prints) with !devobj command. 
This is the example I did on my system -- I picked up a random device with name \device\0000006a as an example (just to confuse you :->)

```
    0: kd> !object \device\0000006a
Object: fffffa8007959630  Type: (fffffa8006bce2d0) Device
    ObjectHeader: fffffa8007959600 (new version)
    HandleCount: 0  PointerCount: 6
    Directory Object: fffff8a00000b8f0  Name: 0000006a
0: kd> !devobj fffffa8007959630
Device object (fffffa8007959630) is for:
 0000006a \Driver\ACPI DriverObject fffffa8006b25d00
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 1 Type 00000032 Flags 00003040
Dacl fffff9a100092d31 DevExt fffffa800792e7d0 DevObjExt fffffa8007959780 DevNode fffffa800796db10
ExtensionFlags (0x00000800)
                             Unknown flags 0x00000800
AttachedDevice (Upper) fffffa800907d040 \Driver\i8042prt
Device queue is not busy.
```

The \driver should give you a hint on what the device is.

Comment: Found out it's a HID USB device. That narrows it down a lot.